# Decision tree construction using c4.5 algorithm?

Tags: java, decision-tree

For the implementation of a decision tree using c4.5 algorithm,I take a numerical dataset,but how to find the threshold value for the dataset.

Comment: But I don't think that is an optimal method for finding the threshold.How they take 75 as the threshold value for Humidity.Is they pick randomly?

Comment: Another good question on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629398/c4-5-algorithm-continuous-data

Comment: It give correct answer for small datasets(14 rows),But for a large dataset(1726 rows)Is it a good method?